Real Time Area calculation while drawing polygon in ArcMap
How can I visualise real-time area while drawing a polygon in ArcMap 10.8?
I mean, when we draw a polygon in Google Earth Pro, it shows real-time area with each drawing vertex.

I don't believe this is possible, real-time area as you sketch your feature. Graphics allow this but then you are sketching into a graphic layer not a real feature class. Interestingly ArcGIS Pro also behaves similarly in that as you sketch a feature it shows no information in the status bar, unless I have missed some setting?

You are right. I did not find any solution by myself. Alternatively, I turned on polygon area annotation and redraw polygon to draw the desired area polygon. It was hectic but I somehow managed to complete the task.
